# How to fix loading file or assembly from asp.net using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am setting up the Sitefinity Development Environment using Visual Studio 2017. 
I have installed `Telerik.Sitefinity.All` package from NuGet Package Manager and it installed just fine.

After the installation I had to build the project and when I hit "Build" an error appeared.

> The "OpenAccessEnhancer" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Progress\Sitefinity\Projects\Default2\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2018.0.1127.1\tools\enhancer\enhancer.exe. 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Progress\Sitefinity\Projects\Default2\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2018.0.1127.1\tools\enhancer\enhancer.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.    SitefinityWebApp

What is the part that is missing here?

Comment: Check the telerik version as well as check the reference to the Telerik.OpenAcces.* assemblies in your project. They should point to version 2015.2.***.

Comment: @Niteen, that's not necessarily true. OP, what is the sitefinity version?

Comment: @Veselin Vasilev the Sitefinity version is 12

Comment: Do you actually have that file in the cited location?

Comment: @Veselin Yes I have checked it many times and it is in the same path. I might have solved the issue by following here https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather/issues/58 . I had to open up the project code source to delete and insert a code. It worked for me but again I am facing some other challenges.